# Directive not recognizing passed in variable

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a a directive that is shown after an event is broadcast.  In handling the event, I set the variable I need passed to the directive.  But in the scope it is always undefined.  I included the 'profile' variable that I am also using, and that is set correctly as part of the Calling controller.  When the directive is rendered, it has profile populated but not vendor if, even though the "on" event has run and set the step number to 3 with a valid Id.  So Confused

My HTML Code

```
<div ng-if="oc.stepNumber == 3">
    <store-Menu profile="oc.selectedProfile" vendorId="oc.selectedVendor" />
</div>
```

My directive (simplified)

```
export class StoreMenuDirective implements ng.IDirective {
     templateUrl = 'app/_customer/orderingV2/storeMenu/storeMenu.html';
     scope = {
         profile: '=',
         vendorId: '='
      };
      controller = StoreMenuController;
      controllerAs = 'smc';
  }
```

The respective controller:

```
    constructor(private $scope: any) {

         alert('VendorId in SMC: ' + $scope.vendorId); --Always undefined
         this.profile = $scope.profile;   --Always Set
    }
```

The Calling controller

```
     $scope.$on('orderMenuSelected', angular.bind(this, (event: any, data: any) => {
        this.selectedVendor = data.vendorId;
        alert('VendorId in OC: ' + data.vendorId);  //is Set here correctly.

        //directive is rendered here, but the vendor id never makes it
        this.stepNumber = 3;
    }));
```

Comment: did you try using var smc = this; then using alert('VendorId in SMC: ' + smc.vendorId);

Answer (score 1):

`AngularJS` **normalizes** an element's tag and attribute name. HTML is case-insensitive, so, `AngularJS` refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

The **normalization** process is as follows:

1. Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
2. Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to camelCase.

So, with that being said, your HTML attribute for `vendorId` should look like this

```
vendor-id="oc.selectedVendor"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot.  Its been about 2 years since I had to do real work on this project, and completely forgot the whole lowercase thing.  Thanks.